# Stylesheet QmainWindow does not work on pyqt5, only qt designer preview

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtstylesheets

stylesheet Qt designer:

```
QMainWindow {
                
    background-image: url(:/tela/app_imagens/kawaii-1546834.png);
                background-repeat: no-repeat; 
                background-position: center;
 }
```

In the preview of the qt designer the stylesheet works normally:

[image: qt]

however when running the application nothing appears:

[image: app]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens is that Qt Designer compiles the .qrc and imports it unlike your script which does not. The solution is:

1. Compile the .qrc:

```
pyrcc5 file.qrc -o file_rc.py
```

2. and import it into your .py:

```py
import file_rc
```